# How to set get request call type to 'document'?

Tags: javascript, jquery, get, xmlhttprequest

How can I set get request call type to 'document' like the attached image? Its showing type "xhr" for me in network tab console.

Can anyone please help?

[image]

Comment: What specific problem are you trying to solve? those types are determined internally by the browser/console

Comment: I am trying to send a get request to download a zip folder. I don't need XHR

Comment: Use headers on server to force download? If you do that you can redirect to that url and current page won't be affected. Clarification comment is still a bit vague

Comment: I am doing this but its showing the type "xhr"

Comment: $.ajax({
            url: urls,
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            type: 'GET',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
        })
        .done(function(response){
            window.location = response;
        })
        .fail(function(error){
            console.log(error);
        });

Comment: Using `jsonp` makes no sense. That is a script request. Please edit the question to properly explain your issue in full detail along with whatever code is relevant

Comment: even I remove jsonp, its a xhr call.

Comment: Basically, I need an HTTP get request without ajax call.

Comment: so just to the `location.href ='....'`. If server is set to force download at that url nothing will change on current page and typical browser download handling kicks in

Comment: Yes, I tried that also but its changing the page URL. Can we prevent that?

Comment: Only if you control the server side code and can set headers. Or use a proxy on server you do control

Comment: cool, seems you saved my life. Thanks Charlietfl!!